# Nodejs Mysql ending

Tags: mysql, node.js

how to check if query ends in nosejd mysql

```
   var query = connection.query(...);
```

i have used this and worked

```
   query.on('end', function() {



  });
```

but i want another way to do this like

```
        if(query.end){

         //do something
              }
```

i know this is silly question but i need this instead of other function to do something else or otherwise i want to know how to call query on end

Comment: No. One is async the other is synchronous.

Comment: this is indeed a silly question, because Node isn't going to wait for MySQL to be done, that could take forever (Node has other things to do in the mean time). If you read [The actual documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql), you'll see how you're supposed to use this, and when you know the query has finished.